# C# Edit [JsonProperty] to hide password with Regex

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following property:

```
    [JsonProperty("Comments__c")]
    public string Comments__c { get; set; }
```

And sometimes sentitive information, specifically passwords, come in the value, like:

```
... ,"Comments__c":"30/07/19 - John Doe : www.site.com\r\n\r\nUser ID: user\r\nPassword: MrqRXgUXXIF4S2FkEWNvvcA",...
```

So, I need to edit anyway the value in the serialization, so when we have the word Password: it replaces everything ahead for XXXXXXX like:

```
... ,"Comments__c":"30/07/19 - John Doe : www.site.com\r\n\r\nUser ID: user\r\nPassword: XXXXXXX",...
```

I was checking the [Newtonsoft Json Classes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json.htm), but didn't find anything helpfuls, maybe I have to do it in the serialization?

Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hum: storing a plain-text password in a comment field doesn't seem like such a good idea anyway

Comment: You would need to apply a custom `JsonConverter`.  See e.g. [running a transformation on a Json DeserializeObject for a property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38351661/3744182) or [How can I encrypt selected properties when serializing my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29196809/3744182).  Do those two questions answer yours also, or do you need more specific help?

Answer (score 0):

Newtonsoft Json API extends dozens of various extension points to attach your logic there. So far your situation looks like a need in custom converter evaluating a string content and mutating it if there is a match: [create custom json converter that masks sensitive information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587565/create-custom-json-converter-that-masks-sensitive-information)

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm